# Can we access method variables with PostSharp?

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

I have a lot of methods that are doing the exact same `if` checks. Is it possible to wrap these methods in some way so I don't have to repeat the check?

For example, I have lots of methods like these:

```
public void Method1(int i)
{
    if (isThisTrue())
    {
        SomeMethod(i, 2, 3); // returns void
    }
    else
    {
        SomeMethod2(i, "TestString"); // returns void
    }
}

public string Method2()
{
    if (isThisTrue())
    {
        return OtherMethod(1, true);
    }
    else
    {
        return OtherMethod2(1, "RandomString", 2);
    }
}
```

Because the body of the `if` else `else` clauses is different, a [simple cache aspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/example-cache) does not work. I thought about creating an `Action` or a `Func` for this, but the methods (`SomeMethod`, `SomeMethod2`, `OtherMethod`, and `OtherMethod2`) signatures are different. Having a whole bunch of them for every possible method signatures doesn't seem sustainable.

Is there a simple way to abstract this out?

Comment: If you can not share your code, post example that match your code. In question you mentioned **method signatures are different** and in your example code it is same. This makes confusion.

Comment: Can you give an actual example of the methods you are working with?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya & @RagtimeWilly: The example has been updated. I meant the body of the `if` clause and `else` clause can be different, but the wrapping method can be different also.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want to return void in some instances makes it a bit awkward as void doesn't work with generics. You could do something like this though:

```
public void Method1(int i)
{
    this.PredicateMethod(
        NullFunc(() => SomeMethod(i, 1, 2)),
        NullFunc(() => SomeMethod2(1, "RandomString")));
}

public string Method2()
{
    return this.PredicateMethod(
        () => OtherMethod(1, true), 
        () => OtherMethod2(1, "RandomString", 2));
}

private Func<object> NullFunc(Action a)
{
    return new Func<object>(() =>
        {
            a();
            return null;
        });
}

private T PredicateMethod<T>(Func<T> trueMethod, Func<T> falseMethod)
{
    return IsThisTrue() ? trueMethod() : falseMethod();
}
```

Or implement a base class to capture the logic:

```
public abstract class PredicateBase
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _predicate;

    protected PredicateBase(Func<bool> predicate)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
    }

    protected T PredicateMethod<T>(Func<T> trueMethod, Func<T> falseMethod)
    {
        return _predicate() ? trueMethod() : falseMethod();
    }

    protected void PredicateMethod(Action trueMethod, Action falseMethod)
    {
        if (_predicate()) 
            trueMethod();
        else
            falseMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to one of the options that were considered within the team when we discussed this internally. However, I have a hard time justifying that this is easily comprehensible. It seems like a lot of work just to get 1 `if` statement abstracted out. I have a hard time telling my fellow developers to use this approach instead of just copying and pasting `if` statements around. 

Thank you for your help regardless. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @PeterHan You could also implement a base class to capture logic as shown in updated answer. Could then be re-used across multiple classes. Personally, I'd prefer this approach to having the same `if` statement copied and pasted throughout code but I can see where you're coming from.

Answer (score -2):

You can use optional parameters is much better than spaghetti code!

```
public object Method(int i = -999)
{

    if(i != -999){//Method #1
        if (isThisTrue())
        {
            SomeMethod(i, 2, 3); // returns void
        }
        else
        {
            SomeMethod2(i, "TestString"); // returns void
        }
    }else{//Method #2
        if (isThisTrue())
        {
            return OtherMethod(1, true);
        }
        else
        {
            return OtherMethod2(1, "RandomString", 2);
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, you misread my example. The methods have different return type.

Comment: Hoo I see! what you mean